# Watir Invisible Button Breaking Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, button, watir, exists

I'm using `Watir` to load a page.  It loads items, and has a **LOAD MORE** button at the bottom if there are further products.

In the `HTML` the button exists even if there are no more items to load, but it's invisible.  So my logic breaks.

Instead of relying on a `rescue`, how can `Watir` handle this instead?  My current qualifier is the following:

`if a.button(class: 'load-more-button action').exist?`

It does exist, however in the visible page, the button is hidden because there are no more items to load.  Hence confusion.

There is no `.visible?` method that I can find.  So there's a difference between visible and what's always reported as true in the `HTML`.

Anybody know how I can qualify the presence of this `element`?  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#visible?` method is now aliased with the `#present?` method.
It will return false if the element does not exist in the DOM, or if it exists but is not displayed on the page.

https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/v7.1.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb#L537

Comment: I see.  `.visible?` is not in the docs that I can find, but `.present?` is.  Cheers

Comment: yeah, probably a limitation of the doc generator since it is an alias. We're encouraging people to use `#present?` at this point.

Comment: If you have the ability to modify the docs, then perhaps keep that entry, even as an alias, and an explanation.  Or forward that alias to `.present?`.   It was more logical as I’ve not seen the latter before in other gems.

Comment: The docs are automatically generated by yard, and aliases are documented as: "Also known as: visible?". https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir%2FElement:present%3F

Comment: I'm not versed on the structure of gems and their `.innerstuff`, but I was thinking it's good to have notes on `.visible?` pointing towards `.present?`, that's all.  Cheers

Comment: I just don't understand where you want it to be clarified. If you search for it in the code, it is there, if you search for it in rubydocs, it is there. If you tried to use it, it would just work. Where were you looking that made it confusing?

Comment: I’m not at home right now.  I was searching on the main methods list for `.visible?`.

Comment: On RubyDocs? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Will respond when I can look it up.  RubyDocs, I think.  In the meantime, go to the Docs in Guides, and look at **browser** `methods` for a lack of `visible?`.

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Browser There is no mention of `.visible?` at all, which is how I approached this.

Comment: Ah, yes. `#visible?` is an element method, not a browser method.

Comment: Ah right!   Ok then.  Heh.